# URL redirect not working in web.config

Tags: asp.net, redirect

I've moved my blog to a different domain, and am trying to set up some redirect rules to redirect traffic. I have added the following to the `system.webServer` section of my web.config...

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="URL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="oldurl.aspx" ignoreCase="true" />
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://newdomain.com/newurl" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

...but it doesn't redirect.

I've tried using URLs of the following forms in the `url` attribute of the `<action>` tag, but it doesn't make any difference...

```
^/oldurl.aspx
/oldurl.aspx
http://olddomain.com/oldurl.aspx
```

Anyone any ideas what I'm doing wrong? As far as I can see, I've done the same as all the blog posts and SO answers suggest.

Not sure if it's relevant, but the old blog used dasBlog.

Comment: I haven't had to do this before but [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1118830/Easy-Way-to-Fix-Outdated-Links-URL-Rewrite-Rule-in) looks promising.

Comment: You could also achieve the redirect by adding the following meta tag to the index page of your old website: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://newdomain.com/newurl'" />`.

Comment: @prd Thanks for the suggestion, but I need to do this on a page-by-page basis. I want to redirect certain pages on the old site to the equivalents on the new, but leave some of the old pages as they are. Thanks anyway.